# How to add React build files into existing JSP project

Tags: reactjs, jsp

I have build a react app with some external libraries and would like to include it into an existing project that has nothing put JSP's.

Running the command `react-scripts build` generates files in a build folder.

- build/asset-manifest.json
- build/favicon.ico
- build/index.html
- build/manifest.json
- build/precache-manifest.23802519359aee1ffa0ec2f3ba332c80.js
- build/work.js
- build/static
- build/tab.png

What do I include and how do I include these files.

I have tried to add the `index.html` into `index.jsp` but is doesnt seem to work. Although I do see the title change to what is in my react app.

`<%@include file="index.html"%>`

or do I need to include all the files similar to how I added `index.html`

The `index.html` file does load a couple of script files in the `build/js` folder like so below.

`<script src="/static/js/2.57fa75d6.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.fe75a1b9.chunk.js"></script>`

Comment: Do I also need to load react via a CDN?

Answer (score 0):

I have project with similar requirements as yours.
Some info needs to be render at server, but could not find proper way to do it in java, so I created maven plugin for that:

https://github.com/maasdi/react-assets-maven-plugin

You can try check it out, hope that can help with yours.

Comment: Okay ill take a look. Thanks for the comment!