# What is the Approach To Migrate Web Application

Tags: html, reactjs, web, web-applications, web-architecture

I am looking for varous patterns to break existing JSP/Servlet based old web application to new react based component based application.

We have site, which calculates premiums as a quotation, if customer is happy he does the application creation and then he pays for it.
We can say that it is a customer portal, who can do this along with other transactions.

Looking for various patters by which we can go for new platform like: start launch with only calculation interface as MVP and rest is existing then we add new features. Slowly we implement all in new web app and decomission existing one.
Assumption is I will have Backend for front end(Experience layer) which will abstract the service layer.

I was thinking build small apps which will be stateless and independent to exiting app.
We just save the state in new then pass it to existing app to resume the process.

I see some relevent discussion already about this as a one way
[How to add React build files into existing JSP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867942/how-to-add-react-build-files-into-existing-jsp-project)

Another way I could think is built SSO in front and do federation between old JSP and new react app.